# Impedir cadastro duplicado com C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Estou com dificuldades em relação ao cadastro em duplicidade. Como faço para que após o usuário preencher o formulário, na hora de salvar, os dados sejam comparados ao que estão no banco, caso tenha qualquer campo repetido ele não salve os dados do formulário?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CadastrarProspect(string prospectnome, string prospectemail, string prospectcelular, string prospecttelefone, string prospectanotacao)
        {
            //Pegar Vendedor Logado
            var model = new ProspectViewModel();

            model.Prospect.IdVendedor = VariaveisDeSessao.VendedorLogado.IdVendedor;
            model.Prospect.DsNome = prospectnome;
            model.Prospect.DsEmail = prospectemail;
            model.Prospect.DsCelular = prospectcelular.Replace("-", "").Replace(".", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(" ", "");
            model.Prospect.DsTelefone = prospecttelefone.Replace("-", "").Replace(".", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(" ", "");
            model.Prospect.DsAnotacao = prospectanotacao;

            var prospAdd = new ProspectBLL().AdicionarProspect(model.Prospect);

            if (prospAdd == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Prospect", new { mensagem = "Erro no Cadastro." });
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Prospect");
            }
        }
```

```cs
   public class ProspectBLL : BaseBLL
    {
        //Adicionar Prospect
        public long AdicionarProspect(Prospect prospect)
        {
            try
            {
                prospect.FgAtivo = true;
                prospect.FgExcluido = false;
                prospect.DtCriacao = DateTime.Now;
                prospect.DtAlteracao = DateTime.Now;
                banco.Prospect.Add(prospect);
                return banco.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                new Logger.Logger().FazerLogAsync(ex, new { Tipo = "Erro", Mensagem = "Erro ao adicionar novo vendedor" }, Logger.EnumTiposDeLog.TiposDeLog.Erro);
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Novo prospect</h3>
            </div>
            <form method="post" action="/Prospect/CadastrarProspect">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nome" class="col-form-label">Nome*</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeprospect" name="prospectnome" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-form-label">E-mail</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailprospect" name="prospectemail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="celular" class="col-form-label">Celular*</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="celularprospect" name="prospectcelular" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="telefone" class="col-form-label">Telefone</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefoneprospect" name="prospecttelefone">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="anotacao" class="col-form-label">Anotação</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="anotacaoprospect" name="prospectanotacao" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="camposobrigatorios" class="col-form-label">*Campos obrigatórios</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnOK">Salvar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Poderia editar sua pergunta e adicionar o seu código atual? Precisamos ver como está o seu modelo de aplicação para lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Cara, ao meu ver você tem duas opções.

A primeira delas é criar um constraint na tabela do banco que impossibilite a criação de registros duplicados. Nesse caso o próprio banco irá retornar um erro avisando que já existe este registro.

Outra opção é fazer a pesquisa antes de salvar. Você pode fazer alguma coisa do tipo:

```
public long AdicionarProspect(Prospect prospect)
    {
        try
        {
            if (banco.Prospect.Any(x => x.DsNome == prospect.DsNome)) // Aqui você coloca todos os campos que não podem ser duplicados
                throw new Exception("Registro duplicado");

            prospect.FgAtivo = true;
            prospect.FgExcluido = false;
            prospect.DtCriacao = DateTime.Now;
            prospect.DtAlteracao = DateTime.Now;
            banco.Prospect.Add(prospect);
            return banco.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Logger.Logger().FazerLogAsync(ex, new { Tipo = "Erro", Mensagem = "Erro ao adicionar novo vendedor" }, Logger.EnumTiposDeLog.TiposDeLog.Erro);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Espero que te ajude, vlw

Comment: Esse trecho eu coloco na BLL certo ? E a parte da controller como posso chamar ?

Comment: A principio a controller não precisa de alteração, porque a Exception retornará 0 e exibirá a mensagem "Erro no Cadastro". Caso você precise mostrar mensagens diferenciadas para cada tipo de erro podes definir alguns código e na controller mudar a mensagem de erro de acordo com o código.

Comment: Ainda não deu certo...  :(